# Ionic, list view like phone contact menu

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I'm searching like a crazy and I didn't find anything. Maybe I'm searching with the wrong terms, does anyone know how to make an alphabetical list like this one in ionic? Specially with the vertical letters?

[image]

PS: I don't want the code, I just want to know the name of it to search more about and learn!

Thank you !

Comment: Did you got anything yet, I am looking for something similar?

Comment: @Lara Unfortunately, [SO] is not designed to mentor, when a general question needs to be answered. You can probably get in touch with outher Ionic users via their website, IRC, or email.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Lists -> List Dividers on https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#list-dividers - this is almost what you've shown in your screenshot.

Here is some sample code from https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-preview-app/blob/master/src/pages/lists/dividers/template.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>List Dividers</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

    <ion-item-group>
      <ion-item-divider color="light">A</ion-item-divider>
      <ion-item>Angola</ion-item>
      <ion-item>Argentina</ion-item>
      <ion-item>Armenia</ion-item>
      <ion-item>Australia</ion-item>
      <ion-item>Austria</ion-item>
    </ion-item-group>

    <ion-item-group>
      <ion-item-divider color="light">B</ion-item-divider>
      <ion-item>Bangladesh</ion-item>
      <ion-item>Belarus</ion-item>
      <ion-item>Belgium</ion-item>
      <ion-item>Bhutan</ion-item>
      <ion-item>Bolivia</ion-item>
      <ion-item>Brazil</ion-item>
    </ion-item-group>

    <ion-item-group>
      <ion-item-divider color="light">C</ion-item-divider>
      <ion-item>Cambodia</ion-item>
      <ion-item>Cameroon</ion-item>
      <ion-item>Canada</ion-item>
      <ion-item>Chile</ion-item>
      <ion-item>China</ion-item>
      <ion-item>Colombia</ion-item>
      <ion-item>Costa Rica</ion-item>
      <ion-item>Cuba</ion-item>
      <ion-item>Cyprus</ion-item>
      <ion-item>Czech Republic</ion-item>
    </ion-item-group>

</ion-content>
```